# Java - Turning Integers into Character with a Charset

Tags: java, character-encoding, char, int

I need to convert an int to its char representation.
So I did this :

```
char c = (char) integer;
```

But it doesn’t support charset.
So I thought using this:

```
String s = new String(byte[], charset);
```

or that :

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder().decode(ByteBuffer);
```

But both of them needs bytes. How can I turn an int into a char with charset?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your goal is to turn a bunch of characters into individual integers, right?

Comment: The first line is how you turn an `int` into a `char`. A Charset is for encoding characters as one or more bytes, nothing to do with integers. An `int` is 32-bit and could store up to 4 characters.

Comment: @DylanMeeus No, my goal is to convert a kind of Unicode (\xXX, X are hexadecimal numbers). So far I found a way to retrieve the number. But since the value is between 0 and 255, I can't store it into a byte and keep it positive.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I want to define a charset because depending on the system on which I run my code the same number return a different char.

Comment: @Unit a Character encoding turns a character into bytes and back again. It doesn't use an `int` nor does it produce a different character depending on the encoding (except if the character is not supported)  If you want to map different `int` values to a character, I suggest using an array which defines all the mapping you want. In any case, there is no standard way to do this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey To be exact, the number comes from char encoding and it could be saved in a byte. (I discovered default bytes are -127 to 128 but we can add an argument to have between 0 to 255). So charsets could be my way out! =D